# Should this tag kick the [bucket]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucket) has 322 questions right now. These questions belong to a broad set of topics, such as,

- Amazon-s3-bucket
- Google-cloud-bucket
- Couchbase-bucket
- And sometimes, to denote some sort of data categorization.

Now, we could burn [bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucket), and create separate tags for each of these vendors. Something like, [amazon-s3-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3-bucket), [google-cloud-platform-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform-bucket) etc. <sup>[1]</sup> But the term "bucket" is so common that a lot of vendors have some sort of "bucket" - so there would be a lot of tags - with very few questions.

Another possibility is to create a common tag for questions relating to any sort of cloud storage, such as, [storage-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage-bucket). Perhaps we could let [bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucket) live as a synonym of the [storage-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage-bucket) and retag the rest of the questions.

Also, I am not sure if all these questions are on-topic here, or if they should go to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)?

---

1. [couchbase-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-bucket) already exists and has 2 questions.

Comment: I think (at least some of the) questions for these tags are on topic, as they're about uploading things to the bucket and interfacing with it in a programming language. That's a programmer's job, not a server admins job. A good start would be to write a tag wiki, so others can actually read what's on and off topic for this tag. Maybe go through the [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191)?

Comment: _too broad_, burn it.

Comment: I don't see how an "amazon-s3-bucket" tag would carry much additional useful information vis-a-vis "amazon-s3".

Comment: @ajb I agree with you mostly, but I don't have much experience in the domain, hence I decided to leave the option open.

Comment: Bucket is also a general term for a part of a hash table (e.g. there's [a question on elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520470/elasticsearch-how-to-make-bucket-filter-in-java-api) that uses one for categorization).

Comment: It should be noted there's an [s3-bucket] tag as well. We need some sort of cleanup there